# Get inner array of a list without using ToArray()

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a method that needs a list or array. I don't want to create an overload for it because it's not a trivial method. So I decided to make it like this:

```
public float BoundingBox(RoadNode[] nodes)
```

The **RoadNodes** I have on the client side are sometimes in an array and sometimes in a list. So when a client has a List I have to call **ToArray()** on the list and then call this method but that's unacceptable as it copies the items to a new array. The performance is a big issue so I don't want anything time consuming. So what should I do?

Comment: Can you change the parameter type to `IList<RoadNode>`?  That way you could pass in a list or array and not require any conversion.

Comment: Have you measured the ToArray() case or just decided it was too slow?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The MSDN document says ToArray() "Copies the elements of the List<T> to a new array." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x303t819(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I know. My question still stands.

Comment: @HenkHolterman No I didn't measure. The project is a game that runs 60 frames per sec and in every frame this method is called hundreds of times. So I decided it would make a huge punch on the performance.

Comment: Never assume.  Measure your bottleneck and start there.  Early optimization is the root of much evil.

Comment: @StevenHansen I totally agree. More computing sins are committed in the name of efficiency than for any other single reason. I understand but the project is a very special case. It is a game with Unity using c# 3.5. The game creates its world on the fly using numerous algorithms and it is supposed to run on mobile device. You will kill me if I told you I prefer not to use methods in hotspots of my code.I don't use class hierarchies either.I even use public fields instead of properties. And it hurts me to tell you that I happen to copy-paste methods a couple of times.But I need the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just enumerating over this, you can simply change it to a single signature:

```
public float BoundingBox(IEnumerable<RoadNode> nodes)
```

If you're needing the indexing behavior of both lists and arrays, you can change the signature to:

```
public float BoundingBox(IList<RoadNode> nodes)
```

The first can be more desirable, in that you can write code like this:

```
public float BoundingBox(IEnumerable<RoadNode> nodes){
    IList<RoadNode> list;
    if (nodes is IList<RoadNode>) list = (IList<RoadNode>)nodes;
    else list = nodes.ToList();
    //Do Something with list
}
```